# QR code is not displaying in print preview

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, qr-code

I am doing a project in which I have to print QRcode on sheet of paper from Webpage. I am using a Open source jquery QR Code Library from [here](https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/). Everything is getting printed in print preview except QR code.
How to make it show in print preview so that I can print in real sheet of paper?

HTML code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery.qrcode.min.js' %}" ></script>

 <div id="qrcode" class="center-block centerbox"></div>
```

script code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >

$('#qrcode').qrcode({
 render: 'div',
 minVersion: 1,
 maxVersion: 40,
 ecLevel: 'H',
 left: 0,
 top: 0,

 size: 100,

 fill: '#9400D3',
 background: '#ffffff',

 text: 'test',

 radius: 0,

 quiet: 0,

 mode: 0,

 mSize: 0.1,
 mPosX: 0.5,
 mPosY: 0.5,

label: 'no label',
fontname: 'sans',
fontcolor: '#000',
image: null
});

 </script>
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: Qr code is not getting printed in print preview. it is printing in webpage but not in print preview. any solution?

Comment: @PaulNUK, edited question and removed unnecessary infromation please look at the code again